# Forming relationships among Null nodes in neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV with lots of optional data fields (some cells will be null) in between. For example,

```
A    B    C
1         abc
2    xyz
```

Here, `A` is the only column with no null values. Now, I have to create relationships among these nodes like this `A -> B -> C`. In here if `B` is null, `C` must form a relationship with `A`, else with `B`. How do I load this data in the database more efficiently? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before loading you should assign a unique identifier for each node, if they don't already have a data domain unique identifier.  You should then use that identifier to load the relationships...

The long answer:  Technically speaking, it may be possible to load null nodes AND in the SAME cypher use the internally assigned identifiers for the nodes to load the relationships.  If and only if this is all completed in the same cypher because there is no way to find the right null node once loaded, right?.

Neo4j assigns an internal unique identifier to every node, but direct use of the internal ids in any cypher query is strongly discouraged. (for a number of reasons, but in short, because they are not guaranteed to remain fixed)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the values in the cells of the lines are the unique identifiers of the nodes by the "id" property. And so far there are no nodes in the database (then we can use MERGE, but if there are nodes, we can use MATCH).

Then we need to remove empty elements from each line, and iterate over the elements in the line in pairs:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///data.csv' AS line

// Skip line with headers
WITH line WHERE linenumber() > 1

// Remove null items from the lines
WITH [n IN line WHERE n IS NOT NULL] AS line

// Iterate over all elements of the line except the last
UNWIND range(0, size(line) - 2) AS i

  // Create or find the first element in a pair
  MERGE (N1 {id: line[i]}) 

  // Create or find the second element in a pair:
  MERGE (N2 {id: line[i + 1]})

  // Creates or finds a relationship between the elements of a pair
  MERGE (N1)-[R:next]->(N2)

RETURN N1, R, N2
```